# If statement in Java withdraw method

Tags: java

The objective is to create withdraw method which will substract withdrawAmount from current balance only if withdrawAmount does not exceede that balance. If it does, then we print a message and leave the balance unchanged. It's easy to do with **if...else**, ex:

```
public void withdraw(double withdrawAmount)
{
    if (withdrawAmount > 0.0)
        if (withdrawAmount > balance)
            System.out.println("Withdrawal amount exceeded account balance");
        else
            balance = balance - withdrawAmount;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same effect  WITHOUT using **if...else** structure or **&&** and its brothers?

Comment: Is there a reason you would want to do this without an `if`?

Comment: You can use a `return` to prematurely exit the function

Comment: @vandale: That avoids the `if` how?  You still need to *decide* to `return`.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - `if` is fine but not `else`, I'm going through exercises from Deitel's Java book (bare basics) and `else` in not introduced to a bit later.

Comment: @ScottHunter I assumed that by not `if else` meant that a single `if` without the `else` clause would work

Comment: @vandale: As a subseqeunt comment suggests, you assumed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by using exceptions.  Exceptions *should* be thrown when there are exceptional circumstances.

```
 public void withdraw(double amount) {
   if (amount > 0.0d) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot withdraw a negative amount");
   }
   if (amount > balance) {
     throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot overdraw an account");
   }
   balance = balance - amount;
 }
```

Of course, this code is fine as a hobby example, but it is not thread safe.

Assuming you don't want to throw an exception, you can also "exit early"

```
   if (amount > balance) {
     System.out.println("Withdrawl amount exceeded account balance");
     return;
   }
   balance = balance - amount;
```

Comment: Don't be tempted to use exceptions to handle __expected__ errors, like input validation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP's comment that the issue is actually with `Else`, not `If`:

```
public void withdraw(double withdrawAmount)
{
    if (withdrawAmount > 0.0 && withdrawAmount > balance)
    {
        System.out.println("Withdrawal amount exceeded account balance");
        return;
    }

    balance = balance - withdrawAmount;
}
```

Comment: "...or && and its brothers..."

Comment: From OP's comment: "if is fine but not else"

Answer (score 0):

Just to be anal, avoiding any `if` or boolean operator:

```
String msg = (withdrawAmount > balance) ? "Withdrawl amount exceeded account balance\n" : "";
double delta = (withdrawAmount > balance) ? 0.0d : Math.max(withdrawAmount,0.0d);
System.out.print( msg ); // prints nothing if balance high enough
balance -= delta;        // delta is 0 unless balance is high enough & wA is positive
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by truly **branchless** code:

```
private double balance = -10;

private String[] negativeWaring = { "", "Withdrawing negative amnt!\n" };
private String[] exceedWaring = { "", "Withdrawing exceeds balance!\n" };

public static int isNegative(double d) {
    long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(d);
    bits = bits >>> 63;
    return (int) bits;
}

void withdraw(double amnt) {
    int negative = isNegative(amnt);
    int exceed = isNegative(balance - amnt);

    exceed *= 1 - negative; // only apply exceed flag if amnt is positive
    System.out.print(negativeWaring[negative]);
    System.out.print(exceedWaring[exceed]);
    balance += amnt * negative * exceed;
}
```

The `isNegative()` method will return `1` for negative numbers and `0` for positive.

**EDIT:**

I'm not sure how exactly does `System.out.print()` work, if there are some conditions there, then your code wouldn't be truly branchless.